# How to keyframe the volume of a speaker with python

Tags: python, animation, scripting, keyframes, audio

one can set the keyframe of an objects location with:

```
bpy.context.object.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=1)
```

and it will set the keyframe of the location.
Right now I'm trying to add a keyframe to a newly added speaker that I created with python:

```
NewSpeaker = bpy.ops.object.speaker_add(location=(0,0,0))
```

following that I change the speakers volume:

```
bpy.context.object.data.volume = 0.6
```

this does work propperly and with no issue, so when trying to keyframe the volume like this:

```
bpy.context.object.keyframe_insert(data_path="volume", frame=1)
```

I receive the following error message:

```
TypeError: bpy_struct.keyframe() property "volume" not found
```

It does work with things such as location or rotation_euler, but nothing in the Object Data Properties.

Things such volume min are not able to have keyframes, but volume and pitch are able to be keyframed.

Is there a way to keyframe the volume with python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Volume is a data property, not an object property.

Don't use:

```
obj.keyframe_insert("volume")
```

But use:

```
obj.data.keyframe_insert("volume")
```